# Major or Minor Revision Change when Implementing an Interface

Tags: interfaces, semantic-versioning

I am using [semantic versioning 2.0.0.](http://semver.org/) In my situation I have a concrete implementation of some interface **A** in one library. And I have the interface that's being implemented (call it **B**) in another library.

I understand that if I were to add new methods to the interface **B** then that would be considered a major change for **B** because any library that implements the interface (such as **A**) would not compile until implementing whatever methods were added. My reasoning for this being considered a major change is because you've now made an incompatible API change to **B** (according to semantic versioning). I think that I understand this concept clearly but correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is my question, and the part that I don't understand... What happens to **A**, the concrete that's actually implementing the interface? Does he get a *major* or *minor* revision number change? I guess that from one stand point you could say he gets a minor revision change because adding a public method doesn't make him incompatible like for instance... if you were to *change the name*  of a method... I guess you could also argue that he would get a *major* change because he needs to implement the interface in order to work. Is either one of these reasonings correct, or neither?

Comment: Sorry if it looks cross-posted, I deleted this from StackOverflow but it may still show up!!! Hopefully it goes away soon! (I accidentally posted over at SO first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. so

you have

```
public class A : IA {}
```

and

```
public interface IA {}
```

in different libraries

And I have

```
public class MyA : A {}
```

for which i am consuming your IA.dll

If you add a method `IA.GetAs()`, then yes its a major change because A will not compile until you add an implementation of the interface.

It seems like MyA will still compile when I update to both A.dll v2 and IA.dll v2

However, What if I already have `MyA.GetAs()`? Its possible that my code would end up calling `A.GetAs()` instead of `MyA.GetAs()`. So i think you would have to upgrade the major version number.

In general I would consider any change to the exposed methods/properties etc of an object to be a major change.

Comment: This is how I was thinking about it, only now does MyA get a MAJOR or MINOR update? I guess it may not get any update at all if it's borrowing implementation from some concrete class.

Comment: well MyA would now also expose the new method, so it should also get a major update. Although obviously I might not expose MyA at all in my library, using it only internally.